# How to add dynamic google map to my website?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, google-maps

I have creating a business directory website, so i need to add google map in to my website.
if one user has selected specific city, locality and search category(For eg: Hotels) mean i need to list the hotels names and address, but the problem is i need to display the all listed hotels icons in map.

i have designed website using HTML, CSS, MYSQL, JS.

i have already tried with WordPress, but could not execute properly.

is it possible?? and any other source there? please help me..

Answer (score 0):

Adding a Google map with Places Search box will help you to achieve this.

Check below URL for Example Code

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at **Directory WordPress theme** [here](http://preview.ait-themes.com/index.php?bartype=desktop&theme=directory) but of course you will need to develop this your own. This will help you what you can do to your project!

Regarding putting Marker on Google Map have a look at this sample demonstrated at [google map documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers).

You will be using longitude and latitude to display objects on map. Define your own search for it.

So a sample result from search.php can be this json:

```
{
    search_result: [
        {
            latLng: [40.71958306715651,-74.0379810333252],
            options: {
                icon: "http://preview.ait-themes.com/directory/wp1/wp-content/uploads/sports.png",
                shadow: "http://preview.ait-themes.com/directory/wp1/wp-content/themes/directory/design/img/map-icon/icon-shadow.png",
            },
            data: '<div class="marker-holder"><div class="marker-content with-image"><img src="http://preview.ait-themes.com/directory/wp1/wp-content/themes/directory/tn.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fpreview.ait-themes.com%2Fdirectory%2Fwp1%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fbigstock-young-people-dancing-in-a-stud-34308962.jpg&amp;w=120&amp;h=160" alt=""><div class="map-item-info"><div class="title">'+"Dance & Relax"+'</div><div class="address">'+"276 Canal Street, New York, NY 10013, United States"+'</div><a href="http://preview.ait-themes.com/directory/wp1/item/dance-relax/" class="more-button">' + "VIEW MORE" + '</a></div><div class="arrow"></div><div class="close"></div></div></div></div>'
        },
        {
            latLng: [40.7053026089413,-73.95326614379883],
            options: {
                icon: "http://preview.ait-themes.com/directory/wp1/wp-content/uploads/sports.png",
                shadow: "http://preview.ait-themes.com/directory/wp1/wp-content/themes/directory/design/img/map-icon/icon-shadow.png",
            },
            data: '<div class="marker-holder"><div class="marker-content with-image"><img src="http://preview.ait-themes.com/directory/wp1/wp-content/themes/directory/tn.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fpreview.ait-themes.com%2Fdirectory%2Fwp1%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fbigstock-All-Metal-Bicycle-2378091.jpg&amp;w=120&amp;h=160" alt=""><div class="map-item-info"><div class="title">'+"Bike PRO"+'</div><div class="address">'+"276 Canal Street, New York, NY 10013, United States"+'</div><a href="http://preview.ait-themes.com/directory/wp1/item/bike-pro/" class="more-button">' + "VIEW MORE" + '</a></div><div class="arrow"></div><div class="close"></div></div></div></div>'
        }
    ]
}
```

Use this to map object on google map.